# Meteor JS PubSub based on action

Tags: javascript, meteor

I need your help or suggestion regarding my refresh function. I have this button called refresh that when clicked it will refresh (rearrange the data sorting based on createdAt field). I have been battling for days trying to get this correctly by resubscribing which i am not sure if it is the correct way or not.

Is there a correct way to resubscribe or re-sorting an a collection on the client when button clicked? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with following steps:

- Pass the sorting type(asc or desc) into router query.
- Update the subscribe sorting of server.
- You need to also also update your client side find() methods sort, because when data does not change or few document get updated by your re-subscription, SO the oldest data will always come at first.
- You can subscribe or re-subscribe collection on either router level or template level. If you are using Flow Rotuer then your re-subscribe will not work simply because flow router is not reactive. I prefer to use subscription at template level. Using Iron router query.

Here is the code sample :

```
Templete.templeteName.onRendered(function(){
   this.autorun(function(){
        var sort = {};
       if(!Router.current().params.query || Router.current().params.query.sortType == 1 ) {
           sort.createdAt  = 1;
       } else {
           sort.createdAt  = -1;
       }
       //You can use this handle to show/hide loader.
       var handle = Meteor.Subscribe('subscriptionName', sort);
   })
})
Templete.templeteName.helpers({ 
   'data' : function(){
      var sort = {};
      if(!Router.current().params.query || Router.current().params.query == 1 ) {
           sort.createdAt  = 1;
       } else {
           sort.createdAt  = -1;
       }

      return collection.find({},{sort:sort});
   }
});

Templete.templeteName.events({ 
     'click .refresh' : function(){
         var sortType = value //get the value -1 or 1 from html.
         Router.go('routeNaem',{},{query:{sortType:sortType}})
     }
});
```